# Entity Framework 7 - Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: entity-framework-core

I've decided to use EF7 form my "home made" web application. I created my DbContext which contains this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    options.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=NameOfSQLServer;Database=MyDb;Integrated Security=True");
}
```

However when I run app, I've got this error:

> Cannot open database  requested by the login. The login failed.

That's quite shocking for me, because I used that connection string in `EF6` and it worked like a charm. 
Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework does not change your connection string. It just passes this through to [SqlClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx). You can eliminate EF from the equation and test your connection string actually works with this code:

```
using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open(); // <-- this should fail if the login doesn't work
}
```

Chances are something is wrong in the connection string, the database setup, or both.